# 960 fixed grid for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, 960.gs

I have my website with the 960 fixed grid. I am trying to develop a site for mobiles now using the jquerymobile. Now after using 960 fixed grid i see that it doesn't align according to browser window even after using jquerymobile. Is there any way so that i can load 960 fluid when it is mobile .

I dont want to take the pain of changing the css for my normal website to 960 fluid grid.
I have tried using the `@media` but for somereason it doesn't work.

Some one who has any idea about it please reply